# Change identity column on SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a column that is a primary key and set as identity in a SQL Azure database.

I need to change the seed value (continue from a different number) but the user interface that the Azure portal has does not allow to edit that field. I also see many posts that suggest it cannot be done but they are quite old.

So, can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I have looked around, researched, experimented, and tested, and there is an easy way to do that which does not include creating new tables. It uses a script like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON
GO

INSERT INTO MyTable (IDdata, Field2, Field3)
       VALUES (154337, 'A', 'B')
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF
GO
```

I hope you get that IDdata column is my identity column which I switched ON for a second and then switched back OFF.

Did the work for me. Share the knowledge please so other people do not have to struggle like me.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use  DBCC CHECKIDENT with RESEED option in Azure SQL. you have to create a new table with the correct seed value and load up your old data into it, rename tables, then drop the old table.

Comment: Well, Azure does not allow me to change the column to identity after I have added the data. Have you tried it? What is the way?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution, all be it a little hacky, to update the seed column.

Basically, adding and deleting items until the correct Id is reached. In the example below, this will reseed the Users table so the next new item will have Id of 3500.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

DECLARE @max_id int

SELECT @max_id = max([Id]) FROM users

WHILE (@max_id < 3499)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('','')
    SELECT @max_id = max([Id]) FROM Users
    DELETE FROM Users WHERE [Id] = @max_id
END

COMMIT
```